# Can you recommend a reliable file copying program that deals with file locking?

Tags: windows, copying, locking

I'm looking for a file copying utility (for Windows) that will take into account file locking in the destination folder.

The situation is we have multiple shares on multiple servers where our applications run. Users often leave the applications running, and hence the files are locked.

This causes a problem when we want to update the software (via file copy).

Does anyone know of a utility that will try and copy a file, and if it fails rename the destination file and re-try the copy? It would also be great if I could copy from one source to multiple destinations.

So far I have tried RichCopy, Robocopy and TerraCopy, none of these seem to support this functionality.

Comment: How will you rename the destination file if a running program has it locked? You'll need to close the program first.

Answer (score 1):

Another one to check is "HoboCopy".  I don't know if it does what you need exactly but thought I'd throw this out there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't seem to do what I need.